# Open Vimeo video in WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I'm trying to open a `WKWebView` with a Vimeo video. When I open the view controller however, the screen is just black.

```
class VimeoController: UIViewController {
    var webView = WKWebView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        webView.configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView.configuration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        webView.configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true

        webView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)

        if let mediaURL: URL = URL(string: "https://player.vimeo.com/video/23608259") {
            let request: URLRequest = URLRequest(url: mediaURL);
            self.webView.load(request)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As a sanity check, does your code work if you change the URL to something simpler like `https://stackoverflow.com`?

Comment: I don't see where you're adding the webView to the viewController view. Also make sure the frame is not zero at this point.

Comment: As @JamesP said, just add this `view.addSubview(webView)` after line `self.webView.load(request)`

Answer (score 0):

Did you check how your video is configured on Vimeo?  Check the privacy settings. Confirm it is configured to be 'embedded'. That's step one to confirm.